# asp.net control ID in foreach block. Get value of textbox or <input type=text> for specific clicked ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, textbox

I want to be able to get participantID clicked in a foreach block. here is my code sample in **file.aspx** :

```
 <ContentTemplate>
<% foreach(GroupParticipant participant in GrParticipant){ %>
        <asp:Button ID="BtnAdmin"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Mark as Admin"  
                    OnClick="BtnAdmin_Click" /><br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnRemove" Text="Delete from group" runat="server" OnClick="BtnRemoveFromGroup_Click"/>                        
        <input type="hidden" value="<%= participant.UserID %>" id="participantID"/>                      
        <asp:Label ID="UserIDLbl" runat="server" Text="ID" />
<% } %>
 </ContentTemplate>
```

using this code i'm not getting something. I tried to use `name="participantID"` and `var UserID = Request.Form["UserpID"];` in code behind but this is getting All `participantID` as array. i also tried to use `ClientIDMode="Static"` without success! Or there is another way to send that variable through button ? i tried this:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnAdmin"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Make Admin"  
                            OnCommand="BtnAdmin_Click" CommandName="usergetID" CommandArgument="<%= participant.UserID %>"/>
```

Can someone help me please ???

Comment: try passing the id as `CommandArguement` of `BtnAdmin_Click`. Something like this ` CommandArgument="<%= participant.UserID%>"

Comment: So you are saying passing commandarguement did not help?

Comment: have you tried this `<%= participant.UserID %>` instead of `"<%= participant.UserID %>"`

Comment: @ Nilesh : yes it's not working. if passing a string, i could get it. but binding gave me nothing !

Comment: @Hassan Nisar: this    <%= participant.UserID %> without "" is giving a compilation error

Comment: I think you cannot do this with server controls. Notice IDs of asp controls.